# US Visa Appointment page shows "No Appointments Available" for all locations in Canada

Tags: usa, visa, indian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen (a student) in Canada, applying for a US B1/B2 Visitor Visa. Every time I check the "MRV Fee Details" page in the Appointments website, it shows "No Appointments Available" for all locations in Canada (The attached image shows this).

I have been seeing the same thing for almost 3 months now. Has this happened to anyone else as well? I would be fine with appointments in 2023, but I am confused since it keeps showing no appointments available. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Pretty much all visa services worldwide are experiencing delays. This site https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html for example gives the US visitor visa appointment wait time in Toronto as *439 days*

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Traveller. I have spoken to a lot of people who are seeing appointments in early/late 2023 and I understand that there are delays, but I don't understand why I am unable to see _any_ dates at all. That seems odd.

Comment: Did the people you asked already pay?

Comment: @xngtng They were able to see some dates as first available appointments, and after selecting a date they were able to pay.